# How to add a generated column to a PostgreSQL table with Liquibase?

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I'd like to add a generated column https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html to my PostgreSQL table with Liquibase. I've tried everything that came to my mind, even something like:

```yaml
 - column:
     computed: true
     name: final_blows_death_ratio numeric GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE deaths WHEN 0 THEN 'NaN' ELSE TRUNC(final_blows::NUMERIC / deaths, 2) END) STORED
```

which results in

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: ERROR: syntax error at end of input
  Position: 195 [Failed SQL: (0) ALTER TABLE public.overwatch_player_performances ADD "final_blows_death_ratio numeric GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE deaths WHEN 0 THEN 'NaN' ELSE TRUNC(final_blows::NUMERIC / deaths, 2) END) STORED"]
```

Comment: PostgreSQL can be finicky about things.
The Oracle documentation for [ALTER TABLE] (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) should have some additional context that will help resolve the error. 

If it persists, please reply with the ALTER TABLE code so we can review.

Comment: Check this post https://priitp.wordpress.com/2022/10/11/computed-columns-and-identity-columns-in-liquibase-joelkallmanday/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got an hour to work on it again. This gets the job done:

```yaml
- addColumn:
    columns:
      - column:
          name: column_name
          type: >
            column_type GENERATED ALWAYS AS (expression) STORED
          constraints:
            nullable: true
```

Comment: It helped me fix my problem too, but can you share a reference to what `type: >` does? And why does it not work when the symbol > is not present?

Comment: Hey @AnmolVijaywargiya. It's actually nothing, but a part of the YAML [syntax for multiline strings](https://yaml-multiline.info). It shouldn't really take a key role, so perhaps something was wrong with the YAML syntax itself.